Why is the second assumption (i.e., known population variance) unrealistic when calculating Z-interval for a mean?
I'm learning the calculation of confidence interval about the mean by Z-interval. The lecture said that:

... the second assumption about the population variance being known is
unrealistic. After all, when would we ever think we would know the
value of the population variance, but not the population mean?

Here is my question. Though it seems intuitive that the population variance is more difficult to know than the population mean, but should the mean and variance be two different characteristics for a distribution? Why a situation that we know the population variance, but don't know the population mean is unrealistic?

should the mean and variance be two different characteristics for a distribution? - would you be able to know the second moment using only the first moment?

In fact no characteristic of the "true distribution" is ever known, because the "true distribution" is an idealistic construct (relying on infinite repetition among other things).
Regarding the specific question, actually there are situations in which the variance is "more known" than the mean. Think about a measurement instrument that has been used many times for measuring different quantities of the same kind. If we use it to measure something new, we may have very strong information about the precision (variance) of the measurement error distribution, but not about the mean (which is the new quantity we want to measure).
In such a situation it may be reasonable to assume the variance as known when estimating the mean.
However such a situation is rather exceptional. Note that the definition of the variance involves the mean, so technically one may expect that the mean needs to be known to know the variance, although this is not quite true, because the variance can be equivalently written down based on squared distances between observations without involving the mean.
This means that technically knowing the mean is not a pre-requirement for knowing the variance, and these are indeed different characteristics of the same distribution. However, the most realistic situation that happens almost always in reality is that neither the mean nor the variance are known (by which I mean that enough information is available already that it could make sense to assume any of them known), so it makes sense to say "knowing the variance when being interested in estimating the mean is not very realistic", even if exceptions exist, see above. The "trick" here is to set up a situation in which the variance but not the mean can be observed, and such situations are rare. The measurement instrument situation relies on assuming that the variance is always the same regardless of what mean you measure, which can be doubted even there.
And note that normality and i.i.d. are not known either, but assuming normality often helps due to the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), and something like i.i.d. is required (if not at the level of the observations, then at the level of error terms or the like in more complex models involving, e.g., dependence) in order to learn in a principled way from randomly varying observations about fixed underlying quantities.
Another complication is that if we invoke the CLT, in fact for $n\to\infty$ inference assuming the estimated variance known and fixed (which is technically wrong) is equivalent to inference taking into account that the variance is not known due to Slutsky's Theorem. The $t$-distribution with degrees of freedom going to infinity converges to the normal distribution. Still arguably in most situations, even without normality, inference based on the $t$-distribution and unknown variance is better than inference based on the normal $z$-statistic. At least it's more conservative, therefore "safer", as it takes correctly into account that the variance is not known.
